# Why is Pylons continuing to pass GET parameters?

Tags: routes, pylons, html-helper

I'm building a small application in Pylons, and it seems to keep propagating GET parameters from a page into all the links on that page.  Is there a way to make it stop doing that?

---

For example, my `ledger` controller has a `summary` action that takes a `ledger_id` parameter, mapped with the following in the `routing.py` file:

```
map.connect('/ledger/{ledger_id}/{action}', controller='ledger')
```

Then, when that page renders, I use the helper in the template to build my links:

```
${h.url_for(controller='transaction', action='activity', account_id=account.id)}
```

But the rendered link has the ledger_id stuck on the end of it, even though I didn't specify it:

```
http://localhost:5000/account/27/transaction/activity?ledger_id=1
```

I have visions of a dozen superfluous GET variables accumulating on the end of my URI as I navigate around the site.  Will these continue to propagate?  Can I get rid of them?

Comment: can you use paster routes test.ini to see what other routes may be found by url_for?

Comment: That gives me an error: `Command 'routes' not known (you may need to run setup.py egg_info)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems a `Route memory` http://pylonsbook.com/en/1.1/urls-routing-and-dispatch.html#route-memory